# Understanding the Rsync Algorithm - Python

Tags: python, hash, rsync

I'm implementing the rsync algorithm to identify similarities between 2 firmware binaries.

I took one of the files and calculated for fixed segments the 32-bit weak checksum and the 128-bit md5. They are stored in a array and I sorted them for the 32-bit checksum.

In the paper by Andrew Tridgell, it is stated that there are 3 levels. I'm stuck at level 1 cause I can easily calculate from the other file the two 16-bit checksums. In this level I have to go through the stored checksum array first and compare with the 16-bit checksums.

There are two questions:

- Which 16-bit checksum do I have to compare? Function `a(k,l)` or `b(k,l)`?
- In the stored checksum array, there is the 32-bit checksum, but I have to compare with a 16-bit checksum. Do I have to to calculate the 32-bit checksum back to 16-bit?

The formulas are written here: https://rsync.samba.org/tech_report/node3.html

```
MOD_VALUE = 2**16

def func_a(segment):
    """implements function a(k,l) from rsync algorithm
    :arg segment """
    result = 0
    for i in segment:
        result += i
    return result % MOD_VALUE


def func_b(segment):
    """implements function b(k,l) from rsync algorithm
    :arg segment """

    result = 0
    for i in range(0, len(segment)):
        result += (len(segment)-i+1)*segment[i]
    return result % MOD_VALUE


def rolling_checksum(a, b):
    """ implements function s(k,l) from rsync algorithm
    :arg a function a(k,l)
    :arg b function a(k,l)"""
    return a+((2**16)*b)


def updated_func_a(prev_a, prev_byte, add_byte):
    """ implements function a(k+1,l+1) from rsync algorithm
    :arg prev_a previous a (a(k,l))
    :arg prev_byte power of byte that has to be decreased
    :arg add_byte power of byte that has to be added"""
    return (prev_a - prev_byte + add_byte) % MOD_VALUE


def updated_func_b(prev_a, prev_b, prev_byte, seg_size, add_byte):
    """ implements function a(k+1,l+1) from rsync algorithm
    :arg prev_a previous a (a(k,l))
    :arg prev_b previous b (b(k,l))
    :arg seg_size size of segment. defined in Constructor as input_size
    :arg prev_byte power of byte that has to be decreased
    :arg add_byte power of byte that has to be added"""
    return (prev_b - seg_size * prev_byte + updated_func_a(prev_a, prev_byte, add_byte)) % MOD_VALUE
```